# Download file without passing type in request - Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, file, download

Is there any way to download a file only with response and without passing any responsetype in header?

I need a solution to download the file without passing any extra params in header.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to pass the option `{ responseType: 'blob' }` as it otherwise it'll try to parse the binary blob into a JSON object.

Comment: Then, is it not possible to download a file without passing responsetype?.